# Помощь в реализации ползунка на svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

нужна помощь в реализации элемента интерфейса. Решил я реализовать 1 элемент, скрин его вы увидите ниже, и что-то понятия не имею как такое реализуется. 
Начал писать на  и в принципе что-то получилось, но далекое от идеала. Итак, нужно чтобы в месте где стоит синий ползунок и пересекаются обе линии, стоял ползунок способный двигать их, т.е. если повернуть им влево, то красная полоса уменьшиться, а если вправо, то уменьшиться зеленая, и увеличится другая, думаю вы поняли, и мне этот момент совершенно непонятен, как такое можно реализовать? Объединить 2 ? Но как это сделать, чтобы на них можно было воздействовать ползунком? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это можно как-то реализовать не прибегая к svg буду очень рад помощи, если в примере будет js и вам будет не сложно, то очень хотелось бы увидеть нативный, т.к. изучаю его параллельно.

Мой код:

```css
.grey-cricle {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-85deg) translate(-282px, 16px);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-85deg) translate(-282px, 16px);
 -o-transform: rotate(-85deg) translate(-282px, 16px);
 transform: rotate(-85deg) translate(-282px, 16px);
}
.new-game {
 width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 330 275" class="new-game">
 <text x="135" y="20" font-family="Arial" font-size="10" text-anchor="middle" fill="#A9A8A8">100</text>
 <text x="165" y="20" font-family="Arial" font-size="10" text-anchor="middle" fill="#A9A8A8">0</text>
 <circle r="120" cx="150" cy="145" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="#ccc" stroke-dasharray="740" class="grey-cricle"  />
 <circle r="100" cx="150" cy="145" fill="none" stroke-width="14" stroke="#ccc" />
 <circle r="100" cx="150" cy="145" stroke-width="8" stroke="red"  stroke-dasharray="250 502" 
      stroke-dashoffset="0" fill="none" stroke-linecap="butt"/>
 <circle r="30" cx="150" cy="145" fill="#006EFA" stroke="url(#gradient-game)" />
 <text x="150" y="150" fill="#fff" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle">99.99</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Как по мне, лучше для такой задачи использовать разметку и JS, не слишком такое делать с помощью векторной графики

Comment: Можете описать поподробнее? В общих чертах, а то я что-то ума не приложу что еще можно прикрутить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На мой взгляд такие вещи нужно писать на фреймворках, но можно и на ванильном JS. Остались мелкие баги, но они устраняются уже элементарно и больше подвязаны к разметке svg.

У нас есть 5 эвентов: на нажатие клавиши(только движок), на отжатие клавиши (вся область svg), покидание мышью области svg, и движение мыши.

При клике мы вычисляем абсолютный центр надписи (нужно для определения угла).

При движении мыши мы определяем текущий угол поворота регулятора и отрисовываем его в svg.

Сделал еще параллельный event для обработки скрола мышкой или тачпадом - тоже удобно пользователю.

Если есть вопросы по коду - спрашивайте.

```js
function bind(func, context) {
  return function() { // (*)
    return func.apply(context, arguments);
  };
}

function getPos(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect);
  return {
    x: rect.left + rect.width / 2.0,
    y: rect.top + rect.height / 2.0
  };
}

var radius = parseFloat(stroker.getAttribute("r"));

var curObj = {
  draggin: false,
  dragX: 0,
  dragY: 0,
  cent: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  onMDTasker: function(evt) {
    this.draggin = true;
    this.cent = getPos(this.text);
    console.log(this.cent);
    this.dragX = evt.clientX;
    this.dragY = evt.clientY;
    this.dragFi = 2 * Math.PI / 100.0 * this.value * 0.98;
    return false;
  },
  onMUTasker: function(evt) {
    this.draggin = false;
    return false;
  },
  onMMTasker: function(evt) {
    if (this.draggin) {
      var curX = evt.clientX;
      var curY = evt.clientY;

      var deltaX = curX - this.cent.x;
      var deltaY = curY - this.cent.y;

      var Ksi = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
      var correctedKsi = Ksi + Math.PI / 2.0 * 0.98;
      if (correctedKsi < 0) { correctedKsi = correctedKsi + 2 * Math.PI; }
      var newVal = correctedKsi / 2 / Math.PI * 100.0 / 0.98;
      if (newVal < 0) { newVal = 0.0; }
      if (newVal > 100) { newVal = 100.0; }
      this.value = newVal;
      this.applyOutState();
    }
    return false;
  },
  onWheelEvent: function(evt) {
    var deltaY = evt.deltaY;
    var oldValue = parseFloat(this.text.innerHTML);
    var newValue = oldValue + deltaY / 10.0;
    if (newValue < 0) { newValue = 0.0; }
    if (newValue > 100) { newValue = 100.0; }
    this.value = newValue;
    this.applyOutState();
    return false;
  },
  svgE: document.getElementsByClassName("new-game")[0],
  value: 50.00,
  circLen: radius * 2 * Math.PI,
  applyOutState: function() {
    this.text.innerHTML = this.value.toFixed(2);
    var fi = 2 * Math.PI / 100.0 * this.value * 0.98;
    var circleArcLen = fi * radius;
    var empteArcLen = this.circLen - circleArcLen;
    this.stroker.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", "148");
    this.stroker.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleArcLen + " " + empteArcLen);
    this.tasker.setAttribute("cx", 150 + 95 * Math.cos(fi - Math.PI / 2.0 * 0.98))
    this.tasker.setAttribute("cy", 150 + 95 * Math.sin(fi - Math.PI / 2.0 * 0.98))
  }
}

curObj.onWheelEvent = bind(curObj.onWheelEvent, curObj);
curObj.onMUTasker = bind(curObj.onMUTasker, curObj);
curObj.onMDTasker = bind(curObj.onMDTasker, curObj);
curObj.onMMTasker = bind(curObj.onMMTasker, curObj);
curObj.svgE.addEventListener("wheel", curObj.onWheelEvent);
curObj.text = document.getElementById("textVal");
curObj.stroker = document.getElementById("stroker");
curObj.tasker = document.getElementById("tasker");
curObj.tasker.addEventListener("mousedown", curObj.onMDTasker);
curObj.svgE.addEventListener("mouseup", curObj.onMUTasker);
curObj.svgE.addEventListener("mousemove", curObj.onMMTasker);
curObj.svgE.addEventListener("mouseleave", curObj.onMUTasker);
curObj.applyOutState();
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 330 275" class="new-game">
  <text x="135" y="20" font-family="Arial" font-size="10" text-anchor="middle" fill="#A9A8A8">100</text>
  <text x="165" y="20" font-family="Arial" font-size="10" text-anchor="middle" fill="#A9A8A8">0</text>
  <circle r="120" cx="150" cy="145" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="#ccc" stroke-dasharray="740" class="grey-cricle" />
  <circle r="100" cx="150" cy="145" fill="none" stroke-width="14" stroke="#ccc" />
  <circle r="100" cx="150" cy="145" stroke-width="8" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="614 14" stroke-dashoffset="148" fill="none" stroke-linecap="butt" />
  <circle id="stroker" r="100" cx="150" cy="145" stroke-width="8" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="250 502" stroke-dashoffset="0" fill="none" stroke-linecap="butt" />
  <circle r="30" cx="150" cy="145" fill="#006EFA" stroke="url(#gradient-game)" />
  <text x="150" y="150" fill="#fff" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" id="textVal">99.99</text>
  <circle id="tasker" r="10" cx="200" cy="200" fill="#0000aa" stroke="gold" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: на мой взгляд то что хотел видеть автор вопроса ...

Answer (score 7):

Используетсья плагин [**RoundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html)

Цвета правильные не смог подобрать но думаю такого примера впольне хватит.

```js
let fn1 = $.fn.roundSlider.prototype._setProperties;
$.fn.roundSlider.prototype._setProperties = function () {
  fn1.apply(this);
  
  let o = this.options, r = o.radius, d = r * 2,
      r1 = r - (o.width / 2) - this._border(true),
      svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      
  this._circum = Math.PI * (r1 * 2);
  let $svg = $(document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg"));
  $svg.attr({ "height": d, "width": d });
  
  this.$circle = $(document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle')).attr({
    "fill": "transparent", "class": "rs-transition", 
    "cx": r, 
    "cy": r, 
    "r": r1,
    "stroke-width": o.width - 2, 
    "stroke-dasharray": this._circum
  });
  let $path = this.$circle.clone().addClass("path-bg");
  this._setDashOffset($path, this._end);
  
  // ####---- Добавление border ----####
  let $border = this.$circle.clone().addClass("path-border").attr({
   "stroke-width": o.width
  });
  this._setDashOffset($border, this._end + 1.5);
  let $border_wrapper = $(document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g')).css({
    "transform-origin": "50% 50%",
    "transform": "rotate(-1deg)"
  });
  $border_wrapper.append($border);
  
 $svg.append($border_wrapper, $path, this.$circle.addClass("range-bg"));
  
  this.$svg_box = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("rs-transition      rs-svg").append($svg).css({
    "height": d, 
    "width": d, 
    "transform-origin": "50% 50%",
    "transform": "rotate(" + (o.startAngle + 180) + "deg)"
  }).appendTo(this.innerContainer);
}

$.fn.roundSlider.prototype._setDashOffset = function ($ele, deg) {
 let pct = (1 - (deg / 360)) * this._circum;
  $ele.css({ strokeDashoffset: pct });
}
let fn2 = $.fn.roundSlider.prototype._changeSliderValue;
$.fn.roundSlider.prototype._changeSliderValue = function (val, deg) {
  fn2.apply(this, arguments);
  deg = deg - this.options.startAngle;

  if (this._rangeSlider) {
    this.$svg_box.rsRotate(this._handle1.angle + 180);
    deg = this._handle2.angle - this._handle1.angle;
  }
  this._setDashOffset(this.$circle, deg);
}
/// настройки самого плагина ///

$("#slider").roundSlider({
 sliderType: "min-range",
  handleShape: "dot",
  radius: 110,
  startAngle: 95,
  endAngle: "+350",
  min: 3,
  max: 97,
  width: 16,
  handleSize: "+10",
    create: function (event) {
    this.control.find(".rs-handle").addClass("rs-transition").eq(0).rsRotate(-this._handle1.angle);
  }
}).on("change drag", function (event) {
 $(event.handle.element).rsRotate(-event.handle.angle);
});


$("#slider").roundSlider("option", "value", 50);
```

```css
.rs-border {
  border: none !important;
}
.rs-control .rs-range-color,
.rs-control .rs-path-color,
.rs-control .rs-bg-color {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.rs-control circle.path-bg {
  stroke: red;
}
.rs-control circle.range-bg {
  stroke: #81ce00;
}
.rs-control circle.path-border {
  stroke: #aaa;
}
.full .rs-tooltip {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: skyblue !important;
    color:#fff !important;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.rs-handle-dot:after {
     display: flex !important;
    content: "\f104 \f105" !important;
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 5px !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    color: #fff !important;
}
.rs-handle-dot {
    background-color: skyblue !important;
}
.rs-handle-dot:after {
    background-color: skyblue !important;
    border:none !important;
}
.rs-handle-dot {
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: А как же нативный вариант без всяких плагинов?))

Comment: @Arthur тут ключевое слово "ЕСЛИ" то есть не очень важно :)

Comment: Ладно, в скором времени может выложу нативный вариант здесь, не так уж много кода на самом деле для такой задачи

Comment: @Arthur да ладно неужели не лень ?  

Comment: Спасибо за ваш труд, он очень помог в понимании работы
Но вариант Serge Kior немного больше подходит для моего запроса

Comment: @ЛебедевАртем всегда пожалуйста .